# F# - Natural Sort Of Strings Containing Numbers

Tags: f#, natural-sort

Is there an F# equivalent of [Sorting for Humans: Natural Sort Order](https://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/)? For example, reproducing the following example:

```
Actual (List.sort)  : let strngLst = ["1-5"; "10-15"; "15-20"; "5-10"]
Expected            : let strngLst = ["1-5"; "5-10"; "10-15"; "15-20"]
```

Please advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @matekus' comment, possibly the most correct solution is to port the AlphaNum sort to F#, so:

```
let len = String.length

let isnum (s: string) i = 
    let c = s.Chars i
    c >= '0' && c <= '9'

let chunk s f t = (f < len s) && (t < len s) && (isnum s f) = (isnum s t)

let chunkto s f =
       let rec to_ s f e = if chunk s f e then to_ s f (e + 1) else e in to_ s f f

let int_of_string str = 
    let v = ref 0
    if System.Int32.TryParse(str, v) then !v else 0

let alphanumcmp a b =
       let rec chunkcmp a ai b bi = 
            let al, bl = len a, len b
            if ai >= al || bi >= bl then compare al bl else
            let ae, be = chunkto a ai, chunkto b bi
            let sa, sb = a.Substring(ai, (ae-ai)), b.Substring(bi, (be-bi))
            let cmp = if isnum a ai && isnum b bi then compare (int_of_string sa) (int_of_string sb) else compare sa sb
            if cmp = 0 then chunkcmp a ae b be else cmp
       in chunkcmp a 0 b 0


type AlphanumComparer() =
    interface System.Collections.IComparer with 
        member this.Compare(x, y) =
            alphanumcmp (x.ToString()) (y.ToString())
```

Test:

```
let names = [ "1000X Radonius Maximus"; "10X Radonius"; "200X Radonius"; "20X Radonius"; "20X Radonius Prime"; "30X Radonius"; "40X Radonius"; "Allegia 50 Clasteron"; "Allegia 500 Clasteron"; "Allegia 51 Clasteron"; "Allegia 51B Clasteron"; "Allegia 52 Clasteron"; "Allegia 60 Clasteron"; "Alpha 100"; "Alpha 2"; "Alpha 200"; "Alpha 2A";  "Alpha 2A-8000"; "Alpha 2A-900"; "Callisto Morphamax"; "Callisto Morphamax 500"; "Callisto Morphamax 5000"; "Callisto Morphamax 600"; "Callisto Morphamax 700"; "Callisto Morphamax 7000"; "Callisto Morphamax 7000 SE";"Callisto Morphamax 7000 SE2"; "QRS-60 Intrinsia Machine"; "QRS-60F Intrinsia Machine"; "QRS-62 Intrinsia Machine"; "QRS-62F Intrinsia Machine"; "Xiph Xlater 10000"; "Xiph Xlater 2000"; "Xiph Xlater 300"; "Xiph Xlater 40"; "Xiph Xlater 5"; "Xiph Xlater 50"; "Xiph Xlater 500"; "Xiph Xlater 5000"; "Xiph Xlater 58" ];;

names |> List.sortWith alphanumcmp |> printf "%A"
```

Results:

```
 ["10X Radonius"; "20X Radonius"; "20X Radonius Prime"; "30X Radonius";
 "40X Radonius"; "200X Radonius"; "1000X Radonius Maximus";
 "Allegia 50 Clasteron"; "Allegia 51 Clasteron"; "Allegia 51B Clasteron";
 "Allegia 52 Clasteron"; "Allegia 60 Clasteron"; "Allegia 500 Clasteron";
 "Alpha 2"; "Alpha 2A"; "Alpha 2A-900"; "Alpha 2A-8000"; "Alpha 100";
 "Alpha 200"; "Callisto Morphamax"; "Callisto Morphamax 500";
 "Callisto Morphamax 600"; "Callisto Morphamax 700"; "Callisto Morphamax 5000";
 "Callisto Morphamax 7000"; "Callisto Morphamax 7000 SE";
 "Callisto Morphamax 7000 SE2"; "QRS-60 Intrinsia Machine";
 "QRS-60F Intrinsia Machine"; "QRS-62 Intrinsia Machine";
 "QRS-62F Intrinsia Machine"; "Xiph Xlater 5"; "Xiph Xlater 40";
 "Xiph Xlater 50"; "Xiph Xlater 58"; "Xiph Xlater 300"; "Xiph Xlater 500";
 "Xiph Xlater 2000"; "Xiph Xlater 5000"; "Xiph Xlater 10000"]val it : unit = ()
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the Python 3-liner in that article, I would do something like this:

```
open System
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

let sortNicely l =
    let convert text =
        match Int32.TryParse(text) with
        | true, i -> Choice1Of2 i
        | false, _ -> Choice2Of2 text
    let alphanumKey key =
        Regex("([0-9]+)").Split(key) |> Array.map convert
    List.sortBy alphanumKey l
```

The main difference is the use of the `Choice` type. The Python version cleverly uses dynamic typing in `convert`: Python always considers an int to be less than a string, so `convert` can return either an int or a string and `sort` will do what we want. But in F# we need to be more explicit. I used a discriminated union because it does what we want too: a value of the first case (`Choice1Of2`) is always less than a value of the second case (`Choice2Of2`).

Comment: Ideally, any solution should be able to solve the _Epilogue Example_ in http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html.